# Middle Click scroll up displaces the "close reasons" banner

Tags: bug, review, close-dialog

Normal looks:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

After scrolling down then Middle Click Scroll back up:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

By middle click scroll, I mean when this icon appears:

[image]

And you then move the mouse to scroll in different directions.

Comment: Sorry @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ it wasn't clear before :P

Comment: lol - come on - it's META! And I wanted to use my script ;P

Comment: Nice script. Also I found another bug because of the edit :)